# best practice for dart root access

Tags: dart, path, sudo

I'm the author of dshell a dart package and tooling for building cli applications/scripts with dart.

https://pub.dev/packages/dshell

I'm looking into how dshell should interact with sudo.

The first problem I've come across is how do deal with paths.

If I do a pub activate global dshell, then dart installs dshell and its executables so that they are on the linux path for the current user.

This works fine until you try to run a dshell script using sudo.

e.g.

sudo dshell main.dart.

The sudo command essentially changes the user to the root user. As such the PATH variable changes and the HOME var changes. The result is that the dart and dshell paths are no longer on the path.

Is there a best practice for putting a dart package on a global path so that it (and its dependencies) are available to root and other users?

Comment: So maybe a partial answer. Dart has a symlink in /usr/bin which is on all user's paths particularly the root users.
So I looking at adding a symlink in /usr/bin to dshell. Initial tests suggest this works. The only issues that the install script will now need to run under sudo.